# find all indices of max values matlab

Tags: matlab, max

I just want to find all the indices of the maximum value in a vector in matlab. the max function returns only the index of the first occurence of the maximum. For example:

```
maxChaqueCell = [4     5     5     4]
[maximum, indicesDesMax] = max(maxChaqueCell)
 maximum =

         5
 indicesDesMax =

         2
```

I need the `indicesDesMax` to have 2 and 3 which are the indices of the two 5 we have in `maxChaqueCell` , how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you find the max value, then you find all the elements equal to that:

```
m = max(myArray);
maxIndex = find(myArray == m);
```

Or using your variable names:

```
maxChaqueCell = [4 5 5 4];
maximum = max(maxChaqueCell)
indicesDesMax = find( maxChaqueCell == maximum );
```

This is how you find all of them, not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
[value,index] = sort(maxChaqueCell,'descend');

sortedmaximums = [value,index];
```