# Find function in matlab not returning any indices even though vector contains chosen value

Tags: matlab, vector, find, element, indices

I am using Floris' tip from this ( [find all indices of max values matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126948/find-all-indices-of-max-values-matlab) ) thread to realize a similar function. This has been working great, however now it doesn't anymore.

> "First you find the max value, then you find all the elements equal to that:"

```
m = max(myArray);
maxIndex = find(myArray == m);
```

> "Or using your variable names:"

```
maxChaqueCell = [4 5 5 4];
maximum = max(maxChaqueCell)
indicesDesMax = find( maxChaqueCell == maximum );
```

> "This is how you find all of them, not just the first one."

This is my code:

```
%Choose only highest of pairs if two pairs
HV = max(MCOs)

%Find the indices of the dices to keep (Decide which dices to keep)
maxIndex = find(e == HV)
```

What I want to do is obviously to get an array of indices for all HV in the array e. When I run this code, however, all I get is an empty array. See below.

```
ans =

 2     2     4     6     5


HV =

 2


maxIndex =

 []
```

So what can I do?
Like I wrote earlier it used to work. I am not sure what I may have changed, but I cant recall modifying anything else than the input vector (e) when it stopped working. This should not have any meaning as far as I can see.

I've tried restarting matlab without any success.

I'll be very thankful for any answers.

/Spcaeyob

Comment: What is `e` in this statement: `find(e == HV)`?

Comment: e is the vector where I want to get the values from. Sorry I see now that it's called "ans" here but earlier in the script I've set e = ans

Answer (score 0):

If your code is:

```
HV = max(MCOs)
maxIndex = find(e == HV)
```

Your have 3 variables where you should have two - specifically, `MCOs` and `e` should be the same variable.  It's likely you equated these before, so the error didn't show up; later, after clearing the workspace, the correspondence was broken and so was the code.

Comment: e is the vector where I want to get the values from. Sorry I see now that it's called "ans" here but earlier in the script I've set e = ans –  user3286007 Feb 8 at 1:22

Comment: In the code example you gave, the variable in max() and the first variable in find() are the same, so I think your first line should either be `HV = max(e)` or the second line `MaxIndex = find(MCOs == HV)`

Comment: Thank you for your input. This was not the issue. I tried restarting my computer and the problem was resolved by itself.